# why spring data jpa added hibernate version check for Tuple in 1.11.x?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, tuples

Now we upgraded `spring boot to 1.5.11.RELEASE` which depends on `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.5.11.RELEASE`,with the `hibernate` version `5.0.12.Final` and s`pring-data-jpa-1.11.11.RELEASE.`
But we found that the using of Tuple didn't work for there's a piece of code for `Hibernate` version checking in `AbstractJpaQuery`, can anyone please let me know why add this?

```
return returnedType.isProjecting() && !getMetamodel().isJpaManaged(returnedType.getReturnedType()) //
                ? HibernateUtils.isVersionOrBetter(HIBERNATE_VERSION_SUPPORTING_TUPLES) ? Tuple.class : null //
                : null;
```